# PowerShell script to compile a csv file of all machines and last logged on users

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of writing a PowerShell script that should check every machine on my domain and export the last logged on user to a csv file. I seem to be getting multiple errors which I can not figure out why this is.

Get-WinEvent : There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper

Get-WinEvent : The RPC server is unavailable So far I have wrote this:

````
$computers=get-adcomputer -filter {operatingsystem -like '*server*'}|select -exp Name 

    $data=ForEach($computer in $computers)
    {
    #Who-loggedinLast -computer $computer -maxresults 2
    Get-WinEvent  -Computer $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 1|
    select @{N='User';E={$_.Properties[1].Value}}
    } 
$data |export-csv c:\path.csv -notype ```
````

Comment: Those errors usually indicate that the event log service is not remotely available. Check the windows firewall configuration on the target boxes and make sure the "Remote Event Log Management" group of inbound RPC rules is enabled

Answer (score 0):

first, i think that because you running on WinEvent on each computer in computers, perhaps the first computer it checks isnt online, hence it cant reach the first one and fails.
second, like you got in comment, maybe the RPC rule of inbound is disabled.
i did almost a similar script not too long ago, but to check specific user on all DC machines, and there i did a checkup with test-connection first, to see if the machines are on, and then loop for process of each online machine - maybe you can do something with that too